# Adding a base64 encoded image to Microsoft Word document

Tags: xml, xslt, base64, word-2007, word-2003

I want to add an image to my Word document which should be added as a base64 encoded image. I have a jpeg. How can I add it to my Word document as a base64 encoded data? I did some research and got to know that there is [this site](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp) which converts an image to base64 encoded data. But I have no idea as to how I can add it to the Word document. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Encode your image as base64, and then paste the base64 string into the Word document.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say "my Word document", i understand that it would be one of document types which MS Word can open. And your question is add base64 encoded image into Word document content (no addition resource file).
The answer is using OpenXML Document.

OpenXML Document format allow to add base64 encoded image directly into it source, no new external resource created.

And in fact, when you open an OpenXML Document with MSWord, then paste a image to it, the image will be save as base64 encoded document. You can recheck by open the document with Notepadd++.